# where do I set rejectUnauthorized = false for node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

where do I go in my install to turn of this check:

rejectUnauthorized = false

which will prevent:

```
k@n-mint ~ $ npm install -g yo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm ERR! Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1359:23)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:963:10)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:463:15)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
npm ERR!     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:219:10)
npm ERR!     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:209:5)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
npm ERR!     at write (_stream_readable.js:573:24)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
```

trying

```
npm set strict-ssl false
```

resulted in the same error as above and trying:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

results in

```
k@k-mint ~ $ npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
k@k-mint ~ $ npm install -g yo
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/yo/-/yo-1.0.5.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/yo/-/yo-1.0.5.tgz
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
```

edit 2_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**----

also tried this

```
k@k-mint /etc/init.d $ sudo npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/


k@k-mint /etc/init.d $ npm install -g yo
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
```

Comment: sudo npm install -g yo, you forgot 'sudo'

Comment: Two years later, sitting behind a corporate web proxy. Having the same issues. Nothing helped, except switching over to HTTP registry which is really bad from a security point of view.

Comment: @BenjaminSchmid what is the HTTP registry?

Comment: @FutuToad As you already did above `npm config set registry`. BTW. My issues finally worked out for me after upgrading Node & NPM to the _very latest version_ (using the NodeJS PPA as described on official NodeJS website) and setting upper-& lowecase env vars:`HTTP_PROXY`, `http_proxy`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, ...

Comment: You really REALLY reeeeHEEELLY should not be setting rejectUnauthorized to false. It basically removes validation of the certificate trust chain, which means anyone can issue themselves a bogus certificate, which in turn means anyone can impersonate anyone else. It neuters the core protection of SSL... Unless this is just for a closed development environment, please don't do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
npm set strict-ssl false
```

you can also install packages without https, so no certificate required

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

---

`npm install -g` is install package as global, you may need root permission for global folder so:

```
sudo npm install -g <package>
```

Comment: provide root permission to npm?